# Probability Question (Probability of a ball being in a box)

Tags: probability

So there are three boxes. One ball is placed randomly in one of the boxes. The probability of selecting the box with the ball is 1/3. However after selecting one of the boxes, the probability of the ball being in the box is 1 or 0? It makes sense that the ball exists or doesn't exist after being shuffled, however I don't understand what differentiates it from the situation before. Can someone explain why its 1 and 0 after selecting?

Comment: The probability that we select the box with the ball in it is $\frac{1}{3}$.  Once we have selected the box but before having looked inside, *given all information we have* the probability that we selected the box with the ball in it is *still* $\frac{1}{3}$.  As soon as we open the box to look inside, we will have gained the information on whether or not we have the box with the ball in it or not.  Armed with *this* information, the probability that we selected the box *given that we now know whether we have the ball in our box or not* will either be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: You may want to read about [Schrodinger's Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat)